# Microsft graph teams Meetings record download

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I used Microsoft graph API to create teams meetings.
I can do CRUD operations and all things are OK except that although there are some options about recording in create request object ,but by setting them nothing is happening.
the recording option doesn't show in meeting and no-one in meeting can records the meeting. (even attendees with producer or organizer role )

here is my function with produces request object.

```
   private OnlineMeeting MakeCreateRequestObject(BaseMeetingCommand command, bool isCreateRequest = true)
           {
               var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
               {
                   StartDateTime = command.Start,
                   EndDateTime = command.Start.AddMinutes(command.Duration),
                   Subject = command.Subject,
                   Participants = MakeParticipant(command.Participants),
   
               };
   
               if (command.EnableRecord && isCreateRequest)
               {
                   onlineMeeting.IsBroadcast = true;
                   onlineMeeting.BroadcastSettings = new BroadcastMeetingSettings
                   {
                       IsRecordingEnabled = true,
                       IsAttendeeReportEnabled = true,
                       IsQuestionAndAnswerEnabled = true,
                       IsVideoOnDemandEnabled = true,
                   };
                   onlineMeeting.RecordAutomatically = true;
               }
   
               return onlineMeeting;
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was online meetings which are broadcast don't support recording.
so by setting

onlineMeeting.IsBroadcast = false;

every things work fine.